# When replicating UIAlertView; background is not the same

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uialertview

I'm creating a custom `UIAlertView` (from a `UIView`). I'm trying to get the same background effect (when the background view darkens). So I created a new black `UIView` with `.5` opacity, and added it to the background.

The problem is, I have a tab bar. When the black `UIView` covers the background, it doesn't cover the `UIView`.  Here are 2 images demonstrating my problem:

**Standard `UIAlertView` background:**

[image]

**Custom `UIAlertView` background**

[image]

Here is my code creating the background `view`:

```
UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[backgroundView setAlpha:0.5f];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
```

How can I get the `UIView` to cover the tab bar?

Comment: You didn't show `UIAlertView` init codes at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding backgroundView into self.view.window, not self.view.